# C/C++ isspace() skipping multibyte string characters

Tags: c++, c, string

I have the following function return to strip spaces from string,

```
char *rtrim(char *l_ptr)
{
    char *lptr = l_ptr + strlen(l_ptr) - 1;
    for (; lptr != l_ptr && isspace((int)*lptr); lptr--)
        ;
    *lptr = '\0';
       return lptr;
}

char *ltrim(char *l_ptr)
{
    char *lptr;
    for (lptr = l_ptr; *lptr != '\0' && isspace((int)*lptr); lptr++)
        ;
    return lptr;
}


char *trim(char *l_ptr) {
return rtrim(ltrim(l_ptr));
}
```

The problem is its trimming character the following -

removing leading spaces from "

```
            Ć"
```

removed leading spaces, resultant ""

The character is 0xc6 with a few spaces before it. I have checked the code to include setlocale(LC_ALL, "");. LANG set to pl_PL.isoo88592. Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What character encoding are you using?

Comment: @JohnZwinck From his LANG setting, I'd guess ISO 8859-2 (Latin-2, for eastern Europe).

Comment: Note: `char *lptr = l_ptr + strlen(l_ptr) - 1;` is UB if `l_ptr` is `""`. (maybe also a _long_ loop.)

Comment: If `char` is signed, then the char is _not_ 0xC6, but -0x3A.  Same 8-bit patterned with 2's complement, but different values when promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rtrim()` has multiple problems.

1. `isspace()` is only defined for `int` in the range `unsigned char` and EOF.  For values outside the range 0 to CHAR_MAX (typically 0 to 127), need to convert to `unsigned char` before the implicit conversion to `int`.  (@James Kanze)

   > C11dr §7.4.1 "... the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."
2. `char *lptr = l_ptr + strlen("") - 1;` is bad as that pointer value is not known to be valid.  Need new approach.  This also kicks off a *long* loop with

   `for (; lptr != l_ptr ... ; lptr--)`
3. `*lptr = '\0'; return lptr;` always retruns `""`.  @hvd  Likely the beginning of the string is desired.
4. Suggested re-write:

   ```
   #include "ctype.h"
   char *rtrim(char *l_ptr) {
     unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *) l_ptr;
     unsigned char *end = ptr;
     while (*ptr) {
       if (!isspace(*ptr++)) {
         end = ptr;
       }
     }
     *end = '\0';
     return l_ptr;
   }
   ```

Comment: @user3305937 Should one of the answers well meet the needs of your post, accept it.  After you earn 15+ rep points, be sure to up-vote all answers you find useful.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is how you are calling `isspace`.  `isspace` only
has defined results if the input is in the range `[0,UCHAR_MAX]`
(or is `EOF`).  On your system, `char` is probably signed, which
means that `(int)*lptr` will result in a negative value for the
accented characters (those with an code point larger than 127),
which is not in the legal range.

When calling the one parameter forms of `is...` (those in
`<cctype>` or `<ctype.h>`), you should *always* cast anything of
`char` type to `unsigned char`: `isspace( static_cast<unsigned
char>( *lptr ) )`.  (The implicit conversion of `unsigned char`
to `int` will do the right thing.)

Comment: While you're completely correct based on the standard, are you sure this is causing the OP's problem? If I recall correctly, at least glibc intentionally supports negative values in functions such as `isspace` as an extension to what the standard requires.

Comment: @hvd It would explain the symptoms.  Although as you say, some
implementations _do_ take pains to make it work anyway (except
for `'ÿ'` in Latin-1, which has the code point 0xFF); I remember
that this was the case under Solaris.  (I don't remember trying
it under Linux, to see what `glibc` does.)  I also require that
at least one time in the past, it was not the case under Windows
(with VC++).

Answer (score 1):

If your are working with multibyte characters probably it will be easier to switch to `wchar`, to avoid unnecessary hassle with char(pointer) manipulations ?

And you can use `iswspace` for checking if the character is a white-space.

Comment: His environment seems to say that he's using ISO 8859-2, which is not multibyte.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rtrim` function ends as

```
*lptr = '\0';
return lptr;
```

This cannot ever return anything other than what will be seen as an empty string. In `trim` you then directly return that result.

Depending on how you want these functions to work, you should either make `rtrim` return the original value of `l_ptr`, which has remained unchanged and points to the start of the string, or make `trim` ignore the return value of `rtrim`.

You would have the same problem with all characters, not just `'Ć'`.

Comment: I think returning the end of the string in `rtrim` is *not* problematic, but rather the way `rtrim` is used in implementing `trim`.

Comment: @hmn Oh, sure, I suppose that would also be a valid approach. Will edit.